# Print hexcode in c++, but just "g" is printed

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding following code. When I run it, it prints always just "g" instead of a hex code. Why? How can I output the hex code? Fiddle: http://ideone.com/FjYr2M

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void prepareAndSend() {
    char Command[50];
    sprintf(Command,"%04XT1000A", "076");

    unsigned char checksum = 0x02;

    char* p = Command;
    while(*p) {
        checksum ^= *p++;
    }
    checksum ^= 0x03;

    std::cout << std::hex << checksum << std::endl;
}

int main() {         
    prepareAndSend();         
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just debug your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sprintf(Command,"%04XT1000A", "076");
```

Undefined behavior, turn your compiler warnings on.

```
sprintf(Command,"%04XT1000A", 0x76);
```

You also need to cast `checksum` to avoid using the `unsigned char` version of `operator<<`

```
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(checksum) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, however the output will be "14".  Is it possible to have not int put something that looks like 0x002C?

Comment: `#include <iomanip>` and add `<< "0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0')` to the `std::cout` line

Comment: You weren't meant to remove the rest. `std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << static_cast<int>(checksum) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Cast checksum to int

```
 std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(checksum) << std::endl;
```

Since checksum is unsigned char, the operator<< tries to print it as a character

Comment: But please don’t use a C-style cast – use a C++ cast.

Comment: @KonradRudolph changed.